# Conditionally remove <form> tag when using MVC HtmlHelper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

The goal is to conditionally exclude the opening & closing `<form>` tags which are rendered by the following MVC code:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <label>The Value</label>
        <input name="value" />

        ... more form elements ...

        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    }
```

I am disabling the form on this page depending on a condition in the model. I already disable the individual form inputs, but want to go a step further and remove the form completely to prevent the form being submitted in the event of a JS failure (which is how I disable the form).

It isn't possible to manually put the html tags in and surround them with an if statement - this renders oddly in the editor, showing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to conditionally remove the rendered `<form>` tags with only a small change to the above code, whilst also maintaining the original HtmlHelper. We simply need a ternary if statement and return null when we want to forgo the form:

```
    @using (Model.isReadOnly ? null : Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <label>The Value</label>
        <input name="value" />

        ... more form elements ...

        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    }
```